# VS Code :: C++ :: Error with giving inputs to the program

Tags: c++

I have just setup the VS Code to run C++ using the YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvg4VtYEhKU&t=339s)

Now when I write a simple code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter your first name:";
    cin << first_name;
    cout << "Your name is" + first_name;

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the error

```
PS C:\Users\raman\OneDrive\Documents\C++_Projects> cd "c:\Users\raman\OneDrive\Documents\C++_Projects\" ; if ($?) { g++ Input.cpp -o Input } ; if ($?) { .\Input }Input.cpp: In function 'int main()':

Input.cpp:8:18: error: 'first_name' was not declared in this scope
    
8 | cin <<  first_name;
```

Comment: ***Input.cpp:8:18: error: 'first_name' was not declared in this scope*** The error message is correct. Where did you declare `first_name`?

Comment: it won't ask for input in the terminal. it just gives me this error.

Comment: That is the correct behavior for code that is malformed. It should give you an error. The error told you about your mistake of not declaring `first_name`. You code is missing `#include <string>`  and in `int main()` you are missing `std::string first_name;` above the cin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. First `first_name` is not declared
2. `cin` uses `>>`, not `<<`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string first_name;

    cout << "Enter your first name:";
    cin >> first_name;
    cout << "Your name is" + first_name;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes your right thank you. I am just getting back in learning c++.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves the issue. @user2988694

Comment: I have selected the up arrow, is there any other way to accept the answer ?

Comment: You have to click on the tick mark.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare 'first_name' before using it.

```
string first_name;
```